# Fatal Error in PHP OOP Login Registration System

Tags: php, html, mysql, oop

I am trying to make a user login registration system.All things are going well but when i trying to insert then i get a fatal error and its says

> Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\LoginRegister\LoginRegistration\functions.php on line 11

I have searched and find some topic which said database variable should be `global` .But its do not work for me.Can anyone tell me where is the problem?

Thanks in advanced.

Here is my **config.php** file.

```
 <?php

 class DatabaseConnection{
   public function __construct(){
    try{
        $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=phplogin', 'root', '');
    }
    catch (PDOEXCEPTION $e){
        die("ERROR Database Connection:".$e->getMessage());
    }
  }
 }

 ?>
```

And here is my **functions.php** file.

```
 <?php
  require "config.php";

   class LoginRegistration{
   function __construct(){
    $database = new DatabaseConnection();
}
public function resigterUser($username, $password, $name, $email, $website){
    global $db;

    $query = $db->prepare("SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = ? AND  email = ?");
    $query->execute(array($username, $email));
    $num = $query->rowCount();

    if($num == 0){
        $query = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO users (username, password, name, email, website) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
        $query->execute(array($username, $password, $name, $email, $website));
        return true;

    }
    else{
        return print "<span style='color:#e53d37'>Error... username/email already exist!</span>";
     }
   }
 }
  ?>
```

Comment: Try `$database->db->prepare()` .

Comment: `global $db` has no use there. you declared your `DatabaseConnection` class as `$database`

Comment: Do not work for me.I was trying.

Comment: maybe you need to write like this `$database->prepare("SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = ? AND  email = ?");`

Comment: try with this  $database->prepare("SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = ? AND  email = ?");

Comment: @synan54 Not working.Its problem `Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object` always time.

Comment: can you make some var_dumps and paste here

Comment: you should define $db globally right now $db variable is not global.

Comment: @renishkhunt in `functions.php` i have defined `$db` as `gobal` variable.

Comment: ok then just add global $db; this line to your config.php file before your connection line. then after it's work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your config code like this

```
<?php

class DatabaseConnection{
   public function __construct(){
    try{
        global $db;
        $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=phplogin', 'root', '');
    }
    catch (PDOEXCEPTION $e){
        die("ERROR Database Connection:".$e->getMessage());
    }
  }
 }

 ?>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
class DatabaseConnection{
   public function __construct(){
    try{
        $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=phplogin', 'root', '');
```

this assigns the pdo instance to the variable $db in the [*local scope*](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) of the constructor method. Once this method is left, $db becomes unreachable.

You can try something like

```
<?php
class DatabaseConnectionProvider {
    protected $pdo;
    public function __construct() {
        $this->pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=phplogin', 'root', '');
    }

    public function getConnection() {
        return $this->pdo;
    }
}

class LoginRegistration{
    protected $dbp;
    function __construct(DatabaseConnectionProvider $dbp) {
        $this->dbp = $dbp;
    }

    public function registerUser($username, $password, $name, $email, $website) {
      $pdo = $this->dbp->getConnection();
      $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = ? AND  email = ?");
```